# Razor Form Submission with Extra Information from Model

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am currently attempting to submit a Form while adding extra information from a propagated model. Like my model already has information, and I wish to pass that along with the Form submission.

E.g. TestModel has Name, Date, and ReadTime properties.

In the View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post)){
   @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Name, "Enter Name");
}
```

Notice how my form only submits the name, but I would like the Date to be submitted as well, which is propagated through from some other view. How would I achieve this?

EDIT: Assume that DATE is passed down into the View when the View inherited the model. Like Date already comes with the Model, and I need to pass it through with the form.

EDIT2: Date comes from the upper View hierarchy which calls this Partial View, which subsequently submits a form. I need the Date, which comes from upper view, to be submitted as a part of the form.

Comment: Your questions is not very clear. If the Date is not in your View, how do you expect it to be posted to your Model?

Comment: And, why do you want it to be posted, if it is supposed to be populated automatically?

Comment: I edited your question. View does not inherit TestModel. It used TestModel as a model.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hidden input for Date like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, "Enter Name");
}
```